# Wordpress display custom post type with custom taxonomy and current term

Tags: wordpress, custom-taxonomy

Difficult this one:

I'm trying to all posts from a **custom post type** 'specialisaties' with the **custom taxonomy** 'specialismen' and need to load the current loaded '**term**' from the URL.

Currently I have this code that outputs the term 'superpower' .

```
<?php $loop = new WP_Query(array('post_type'=>'specialisaties', 'taxonomy'=>'specialismen', 'term' => 'superpower', 'orderby' => 'menu_order', 'order' => 'asc')); ?>
<?php while ($loop->have_posts()) : $loop->the_post();  ?>

    <h1><?php the_title() ?></h1>

    <?php the_content() ?>

    <?php endwhile; ?>
```

This loads the specific post with the term 'superpower'. How do I fetch the 'term' dynamically from the URL I'm loading?

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed it with get_term_by .

```
<?php $term = get_term_by( 'slug', get_query_var('term'), get_query_var('taxonomy') ); ?>

<?php $loop = new WP_Query(array('post_type'=>'specialisaties', 'taxonomy'=>'specialismen', 'term' => $term->name, 'orderby' => 'menu_order', 'order' => 'asc')); ?>
```